# Асинхронный метод BeginRead

Tags: c#, асинхронность

У меня есть код синхронного чтения данных из потока.
В бесконечном цикле идет прослушка:

```
    while (alive_tcp)
    {
        byte[] messageLenBytes = ReceiveSync(4); // получили длину
        int messageLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(messageLenBytes, 0); // сконвертировали в число
        byte[] buffer = ReceiveSync(messageLen); // получили полное сообщение
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));
        string message = builder.ToString();
    }
```

Метод `ReceiveSync`:

```
private byte[] ReceiveSync(int nBytesExact) 
{
    byte[] buf = new byte[nBytesExact];
    int readpos = 0;
    while (readpos < nBytesExact)
    {
       try
       {
           int actuallyRead = stream.Read(buf, readpos, nBytesExact - readpos);
           if (actuallyRead == 0)
               throw new System.IO.EndOfStreamException();
           readpos += actuallyRead;
       }
       catch 
        return buf;
    }
}
```

Хочу сделать чтение асинхронным с помощью `BeginRead`, но никак не пойму как получить результат чтения отталкиваясь от моего кода. Нужен ли бесконечный цикл вообще?
Знаю что `BeginRead` устарел, но пишу под netframework 4.0. Может посоветуете другую реализацию.

Comment: Я не прочь поломать голову и помочь в решении задачи. Но дело в том, что асинхронный код действует как: запускается и отдаёт управление куда-то. Куда? Это важно! Нужно знать тип вашего приложения, и куда можно отдать управление. Приведите чуть больше информации, где и как выполняется код.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov приложение простое - чат (сервер и клиент). Логика работы: запуск клиента - подключение к серверу - создается поток в котором идет прием сообщений от сервера. В принципе чат уже работаем при синхронном приеме сообщений и я думаю этого достаточно, т.к. частота сообщений не очень велика. Просто хотелось разобраться возможен ли переход на асинхронный прием сообщений. Из проделанных экспериментов пришел к выводу что асинхронному коду некуда передавать управление, поэтому остановился на том что есть.

Comment: Клиент - WinForms/WPF? Благодаря асинхронности можно избавиться от потока, в котором идет прием сообщений. | Хотел плюсиков срубить... Ну да ладно :)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, клиент WPF. А как без отдельного потока организовать постоянное ожидание сообщения от сервера?